# ASP to access programming

Tags: asp-classic

I have an issue where I need to take a value from a form page drop down. `<option value="English">` (french is the other) and transfer via asp classic to an access database. In the database the Language field is a combo box with values of English and French. Basically I need the asp to turn on the right value in the combo box. What I use now for text fields is:

```
rsAddComments.Fields("Report_Language") =  Request.Form("Report_Language")
```

Please help

Jamie

Answer (score 3):

Just make the drop down field values english and french unless I am missing something?

```
<select name="Report_Language">
 <option value="English">English</option>
 <option value="French">French</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I did that already. I had a mistake the the javascript validation that stopped it from writing. But it is working now.  

Thank you